# Is there a way to set the encoding for all files read and written by python

Tags: python, encoding, file-io

I have a script in python that needs to read iso-8859-1 files and also write in that encoding.

Now I am running the script in an environment with all locales set at utf-8. Is there a way to define in my python scripts that all file acces have to use the iso-8859-1 encoding?

Comment: The check/cheque is in the mail, of course I'll still love you in the morning, and my data is encoded in ISO-8859-1, not cp1252.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't really listen to the environment when it comes to reading and writing files in a particular encoding. It only listens to the environment when it comes to encoding unicode written to stdout, *if* stdout is connected to a terminal.

When reading and writing files in Python 2.x, you deal with bytestrings (the `str` type) by default. They're encoded data. You have to decode the data you read by hand, and encode what you want to write. Or you can use `codecs.open()` to open the files, which will do the encoding for you.

In Python 3.x, you open files either in binary mode, in which case you get `bytes`, or you open it in text mode, in which case you should specify an encoding just like with `codecs.open()` in Python 2.x.

None of these are affected by environment variables; you either read bytes, or you specify the encoding.